# Why my function is not returning a stack (self made stack class) when data is storing in stack?

Tags: java, function, stack

I am trying to first save data in a self made stack data structure's object in java. But problem is when I wanna return that stack to be reused in another function where I can use that stack then it returns an empty stack there. However, right in the previous line I have printed all stack elements and it was not empty. Here is the code:

```
public Stack allLeafNodes(TreeNode root)
{
    Stack stack= new Stack();
    if (root == null)
        return null;
    if (root.getLeft() == null &&
            root.getRight() == null)
    {
        stack.push(root.getData());
    }
    if (root.getLeft() != null)
        allLeafNodes(root.getLeft());
    if (root.getRight() != null)
        allLeafNodes(root.getRight());
    else{
        stack.print(); // at this call all elements are getting printed
        return stack; //but when it returns, the stack is empty
    }
    return stack;
}
```

Comment: Draw your "stack" on a piece of paper and trace the execution using pointers (pen, pencil) to indicate current position and compare with the code. (Note that your code looks like a _tree_, not a stack.)

Comment: Just another note which becomes relevant after fixing the `print` method: you probably forgot to add the results of the two `allLeafNodes` calls to your `stack`. In the current implementation those results are silently ignored.

Comment: You need to include the code which calls `allLeafNodes`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `print()` method realization you use `pop()` method. For its this behavior is normal. From javadoc `pop()`

```
Removes the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as the value of this function.
```

Anyway, your method `print()` cleared your stack.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use some custom class `Stack` (not `java.util.Stack`) with custom implementation of method `print` which could be using `pop()` operation thus removing all elements from the stack.

Thus, method `print()` needs to be revised;  probably it is worth to override `Stack`'s method `toString()` to make sure the stack contents is not modified and use it for debug printing.

---

**Update**

Another issue is with implementation of recursive method `allLeafNodes` in which the resulting instance of stack is always re-created, while it needs to be passed as an accumulator in the recursive calls for the left and right nodes:

```java
public static Stack allLeafNodes(TreeNode root) {
    return allLeafNodes(root, new Stack());
}

public static Stack allLeafNodes(TreeNode root, Stack stack) {

    if (root == null)
        return stack;
        
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        stack.push(root.data);
    }
    if (root.left != null)
        allLeafNodes(root.left, stack);
    if (root.right != null)
        allLeafNodes(root.right, stack);
    
    //    stack.print(); // at this call all elements are getting printed
    System.out.println(stack);
    return stack;
}
```

Otherwise, `Stack` implementation needs to have a method similar to `Collections::addAll` which has to be used to add the contents of "inner" leaf nodes when returning from recursive calls:

```java
public static Stack allLeafNodes(TreeNode root) {

    if (root == null)
        return null;
    
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        stack.push(root.data);
    }
    if (root.left != null) {
        Stack left = allLeafNodes(root.left);
        if (null != left)
            stack.addAll(left);
    }
    if (root.right != null) {
        Stack right = allLeafNodes(root.right);
        if (null != right)
            stack.addAll(right);
    }
    
    //    stack.print(); // at this call all elements are getting printed
    
    System.out.println(stack);
    return stack;
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using my very own custom made Stack class... But the fact that when it prints all data then why is it returning an empty (in the very next line after printing) I tried removing print function as well but problem still persists

Comment: @Techistanpro, please check the updated answer